# Can I Build 2 Separate Apps To The Same iPhone?

Tags: ios, xcode5, overriding, multiple-projects

I know this is a very stupid question, but I have 2 completely separate projects I am working on, one of which is already on the phone, and I want to make sure the second one will not override the first one.

Comment: _I know this is a very stupid question_ - then why ask it?

Comment: Because I don't know the answer to it

Comment: @user3416823 As a new user to SO, don't forget that you can indicate your question has been answered by accepting the best answer. Click the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: soory, it gave me the you must wait 8 minute thing, and then i got distracted with coding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the bundle id is different for the apps, you have nothing to worry about. You can even build and debug both apps on the same device at the same time or even on multiple devices.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your projects specify different executable bundles (i.e. 'com.me.myapp1' and 'com.me.myapp2') then they won't overwrite each other - you can see this in the iPhone simulator - If you run your first app and then your second app and then press shift-cmd-H you should see icons for both of your projects on the simulator springboard screen.

Comment: FYI - using the term "targets" here is a bit misleading since it has a specific meaning within Xcode. It's the app's bundle id that matters (and what you are referring to).

Comment: Thanks.  I have clarified that